# Bootstrap CSS overwriting my custom CSS - Background Color / Image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've read the articles on the specificity of Bootstrap being greater than my custom CSS.
However, I want to add a background colour to the entire HTML page.
When I create a custom style in the following fashion:

```
.backgroundClass {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(51, 102, 255, 0.3), rgba(51, 102, 255, 0.5));
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

and then add it to my HTML tag in Html

```
<HTML lang="en" class="backgroundClass">
```

Only "parts" of the website is showing that background colour.

When I inspect elements they have their own colour of #fff, i.e. white, due to bootstrap.

**Any workarounds or solutions??**

Comment: If bootstrap is overwriting your own code, then most probably your loading order is not correct. Can you show us the part of your html `<head>` where you are adding bootstrap and your own css files?

Comment: I've got it as the bootstrap loading first and then my own css, should it be the other way around?

Comment: No, bootstrap first then your own styles is the correct way. Can you create a minimal reproducable version with your problem? You can directly add a HTML/JS/CSS snippet which can be executed. This way we could direclty put hands on that problem

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by applying `!important` tag in your CSS file as shown below.

```
.backgroundClass {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(51, 102, 255, 0.3), rgba(51, 102, 255, 0.5)) !important;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

`!important` will overwrite browser CSS and will give preference to your CSS.

Comment: Always add CSS link below the framework link

Comment: This, unfortunately, didn't work - I think this solves most problems. However,
When I insert the class in the <HTML> tag it still doesn't give me this background.

It is worth noting that I'm using Django and there could possibly be an issue in the way it's loading in my main.css file.

Even more context - If I add the class to the <body> tag, it works BUT that doesn't cover the entire view port..

Comment: Ah I've been deceived by my dual monitor setup. 
It looks like the background stretches across the entire viewport on my smaller monitor but not on my larger monitor.

is bootstrap's container not supposed to be "fully" responsive? Looks like I have to look at some other threads regarding 
Either:
<meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

OR

bootstrap's container class

Thanks all!

Comment: You should avoid using `important!` if it's not really needed. If bootstrap is already overwriting this style, it will overwrite a lot more of his future style. Adding important to all of them is really bad practice.

Comment: if it will not work try to use `*{ background-color: #FFFFFF }` in css file

Comment: after that use your colour which you want to have above code will remove all your default browser css for background color